# Surviving the masterwork

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Been trying to survive the Masterwork mod for Dwarf Fortress, but im lucky if I can do well enough to have more migrants past the 3rd wave. Its not the wilderness or the ambushes that get me anymore its the migrants themselves. If its not a plague from hell its a psycho with an animated weapon as a pet or my favorite is a necromancer in disguise. My last game I got 3 Vampires in one wave, 3 drained bodies all of a sudden, right after a psycho went berserk and another went mad. In the span of about 3 minutes I lost 6 dwarves out of 17 (not including the 3 dwarven vampires I now have to find and dispose of). Its hard to recover after that and if you dont have a growing wealth migrants just stop showing up.

So how do I turn some of this stuff off or make it past this at all?

Comment: 3 vamps in one wave? Wow. But I suspect you're generating a very young world, where vampires prevail. Try to generate an older world and check if you still get vampires often.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard you are correct a mere 100 years young.

Comment: Vampires (and any other mythical creatures) are more frequent on younger worlds, as they haven't been killed yet.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issues you're having. One option is to use Dwarf Therapist to identify cursed dwarves (you must turn this option on in the settings). Alternatively, and this is what I did, these can be turned off in the settings application with the option "Secret FUN".

Comment: ahh I think your talking about "secret fun"

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it. That option adds a number of cursed dwarves which can appear with your waves. I believe in game you can make totems or something that can help with them, but I just turned them off.

Comment: yah definitly find it more fun to be fighting invaders, not my own dwarves.

Comment: I'm the same way. I don't even enjoy the normal vampires.

Comment: agreed I quit a thriving fortress because my queen ended up being a vampire and I was fed up with it.